# Shear between which two fluids is better for atomisation - liquid & liquid or gas & liquid?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, shear, liquid, injection

In designing an atomizer which generates a spray of liquid, one can adopt atomisation through shear.

Shear in the following cases are to be considered:

1. stagnant Gas- moving Liquid: in this gas case the gas is stagnant but the liquid is injected at high velocity. This encountered in daily diesel IC engines.
2. moving gas - moving liquid: this is used in aircraft engines wherein the fast-moving gas atomises the liquid due to shear
3. moving liquid - moving liquid: this is a not-so-often encountered area but shear does occur when two liquid layers move one over the other.

Comparing the atomization/shear intensity, which of the following will be the highest?